How to get coredump of process running in k8s?
I have a service mysvc running in k8s cluster with hostPID:true.
I run command
KUBECTL_NODE_SHELL_IMAGE=docker.io/library/ubuntu:jammy kubectl node-shell  --context CCC -n NNN worker

In new pod I install gdb and find out where fs of pod with mysvc is mounted and set it to rfs env variable.
After that I copy libthread_db.so.1 from ${rfs}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ to corresponding path in current container.
Also I copy all ${rfs}/usr/{bin,lib} files to current pod /usr/{bin,lib} (dirty hack).
Then I generate .gdbinit file with the script
#!/bin/bash
echo "set sysroot $rfs" > .gdbinit
echo "set solib-search-path $rfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" >> .gdbinit
echo "set libthread-db-search-path $rfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1" >> .gdbinit

And finally I make core:
gcore $(pgrep mysvc)

at this point I got several warnings:
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007fc4114f9719 in syscall () from target:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
warning: target file /proc/4091858/cmdline contained unexpected null characters
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 4096 bytes at 0xffffffffff600000.
Saved corefile core.4091858
[Inferior 1 (process 4091858) detached]

And when I try to load core to gdb:
gdb ${rfs}/usr/bin/mysvc -c core.4091858

I got another warning
warning: .dynamic section for "/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

And threads except first has incomplete symbol information:
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    LWP 4091858       0x00007fc4114f9719 in syscall ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  2    LWP 4091870       0x00007fc41147de96 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  3    LWP 4091871       0x00007fc41147de96 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  4    LWP 4091872       0x00007fc4114f415f in poll ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

(gdb) thread 2
[Switching to thread 2 (LWP 4091870)]
#0  0x00007fc41147de96 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fc41147de96 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc411480558 in pthread_cond_wait ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x000055d4554eb657 in consume_socket (ctx=0x55d4589d8000, sp=0x55d458a028f8, thread_index=<optimized out>)
    at /builds/ceph/mws/third_party/opentelemetry-cpp/third_party/prometheus-cpp/3rdparty/civetweb/src/civetweb.c:19634
#3  worker_thread_run (conn=conn@entry=0x55d458a02000)
    at /builds/ceph/mws/third_party/opentelemetry-cpp/third_party/prometheus-cpp/3rdparty/civetweb/src/civetweb.c:19775
#4  0x000055d4554e7843 in worker_thread (thread_func_param=0x55d458a02000)
    at /builds/ceph/mws/third_party/opentelemetry-cpp/third_party/prometheus-cpp/3rdparty/civetweb/src/civetweb.c:19948
#5  0x00007fc411481144 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007fc4115017dc in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

and for example, thread 42:
[Switching to thread 42 (LWP 4092067)]
#0  0x00007fc41147de96 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fc41147de96 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc411480b2f in pthread_cond_clockwait ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fc4121f3ba3 in std::__condvar::wait_until (this=0x55d458c38078, __m=..., __clock=1, __abs_time=...)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/std_mutex.h:169
#3  std::condition_variable::__wait_until_impl<std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > (this=0x55d458c38078, 
    __lock=..., __atime=...) at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/condition_variable:201
#4  std::condition_variable::wait_until<ceph::mono_clock, std::chrono::duration<unsigned long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > (
    this=this@entry=0x55d458c38078, __lock=..., __atime=...)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/condition_variable:135
#5  0x00007fc4121efaf1 in std::_V2::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, ceph::mono_clock, std::chrono::duration<unsigned long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > (this=this@entry=0x55d458c38078, __lock=..., __atime=...)
    at /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/condition_variable:336
#6  0x00007fc4121ef6b0 in CommonSafeTimer<std::mutex>::timer_thread (this=0x55d458c38060) at /builds/ceph/src/common/Timer.cc:116
#7  0x00007fc4121f3c1a in CommonSafeTimerThread<std::mutex>::entry (this=<optimized out>) at /builds/ceph/src/common/Timer.cc:33
#8  0x00007fc4121e9c9d in Thread::entry_wrapper (this=0x55d458c369c0) at /builds/ceph/src/common/Thread.cc:87
#9  0x00007fc411481144 in ?? ()
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#10 0x00007fc4115017dc in ?? ()
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   from /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/274b9e63585d6bf8d585165156d82f8f0a1cc5f5bd3387a7cb753343191c7cdb/rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

How to fix this? Or is there more straightforward way to get readable core?

Can you put the core file somewhere accessible, copy it out of the cluster, and run the debugger on a developer system?  A couple of the initial steps like getting a shell on the node itself may not be possible in a typical Kubernetes setup, especially by a developer who's not a cluster administrator.
